# Same encoding (UTF-8), but different lengths of string and content (PHP)

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, multibyte

I have two string variables - first variable is set manually inside code (`$date1="14 июня"`), second one parsed from remote page using cURL and phpQuery.
If we print both variables, the result looks the same, but length and content are different:

```
echo $date1; //output: 14 июня
echo $date2; //output: 14 июня
echo $date1[2]; //output is space - third symbol in string
echo $date2[2]; //output is � - it's a part of third symbol in string
echo strlen($date1); //output: 7
echo strlen($date2); //output: 12
echo mb_detect_encoding($date1) //output: UTF-8
echo mb_detect_encoding($date2) //output: UTF-8
```

I wonder if there is a solution how to convert `$date2` to format/encoding of `$date1`?

p.s: There is SO topic about iconv(), but I'm unable to find working solution.

Comment: `strlen()` returns `11` for the text you posted (I copy-pasted the string from the question).

Comment: There are invisible characters there additionally. Show `echo bin2hex($s)` for both.

Comment: Provide a way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Dump the variables with an expression like `var_dump(array_shift(unpack('H*', $dateX)));`

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov, for date1 - `string(22) "313420d0b8d18ed0bdd18f"` and for date2: `string(14) "3134204a756e65" `

Comment: `3134204a756e65` is `14 June`, `313420d0b8d18ed0bdd18f` is `14 июня`.

Comment: sorry guys, I've provided wrong output, please find real output (as you requested): for date1 - `313420d0b8d18ed0bdd18f` and for date2: `"3134c2a0d0b8d18ed0bdd18f"`

Comment: So, cannot you compare them and see the latter has extra `c2a0` bytes there, while the former uses `20` as a space?

Comment: so, your solution is to remove manually this extra byte ?

Comment: It's just a different type of space. It's up to you what you do with it. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm

Comment: downvote fairies at it again. Legitimate question +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have 2 strings:

`313420d0b8d18ed0bdd18f` - this uses [`0x20`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20/index.htm) character as a space.

`3134c2a0d0b8d18ed0bdd18f` - this uses the [`0xC2A0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) sequence of bytes as a space (it's the Unicode's non-breaking space).

Apart of those spaces the strings are identical.

To replace the space-alike unicode characters with a regular space you can use the following regular expression:

```
preg_replace('~\p{Zs}~u', ' ', $str)
```

References:

- [PHP - Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

Comment: Is there any php method for converting all symbols/sequences/characters  like this? For the space character - ok, I'll replace it, but what about other character like that?

Comment: Thank you @zerkms! Now functions like `explode(' ',$date2)` works fine. But the length is still different, I think it's because of Cyrillic symbols. Is there any way to convert date2, I think length of "июня" must be 4.

Comment: @deeplay Use [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) to measure length of multibyte strings. `echo mb_strlen('июня', 'utf8'); // 4`

Comment: I know about `mb` functions. Looks like there is no way for converting. Strange for me, that both of string are in UTF-8 encoding, but with different content. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @deeplay `июня` when encoded in utf-8 is 8 bytes, since the cyrillic characters are all 2-byte long. And `strlen` simply counts the length of the string in bytes. So it's impossible to say `июня` be in utf8 and have the length of anything but 8 bytes.